# How to convert Filemaker Pro Database (have container fields) to mySQL

Tags: mysql, database, filemaker

I have a Filemaker Pro Advanced Database which contains 14000 records. Each record consist of 2 image fields and 10 text fields.

I have tried to export it to XML,HTML which could be imported to mySQL but the image fields are not exportable. (images are stored in Container Fields)

Please help, in a fix right now.

Answer (score 4):

Try is to use ODBC; FileMaker ODBC SQL ([PDF](http://www.filemaker.com/support/product/docs/fmp/fm11_odbc_jdbc_guide_en.pdf)) has special functions to work with container fields.

Another way is to write a FileMaker script to export image fields separately. The script step is called "Export field contents". You need to write a script that loops over records and for each record does the following:

- Calculates the the target file path and saves it in a variable. Note that FileMaker uses [its own cross-platform format for paths](http://www.filemaker.com/help/html/create_db.8.32.html). It looks like

  ```
  filemac:/Macintosh HD/path/to/file.ext
  filewin:/C:/path/to/file.ext
  ```

  The script step should be like

  ```
   Set Variable[ $file, "filemac:/Macintosh HD/path/to/" 
       & MyTable::RecordID & "-1.jpg" ]
  ```
- Export field contents using the calculated path:

  ```
  Export Field Contents[ $file, MyTable::Pic1 ]
  ```

Caveats: if images were pasted, they may fail to export. If they are in different formats, FileMaker won't do any conversion, it's up to you.